# In DataGrid both Header and Footer should be fixed while scrolling in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make Header and Footer should be fixed while scrolling the DataGrid.
Can anyone help me out.
My Code:

```
<div id="divASNArrival" style="overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 205px">
  <asp:DataGrid ID="dg_ASN_Arrival" runat="server" Width="98%" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="150"
                CellPadding="4"  BorderWidth="1px" BorderStyle="Solid">
```

Comment: My dear friend please give us some code, what you have tried so far...

Comment: You firstly google it out. If you get stuck then ask again. Check [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=asp%3ADataGrid+fixed+header+footer&oq=asp%3ADataGrid+fixed+header+footer&gs_l=psy-ab.3...60992.65838.0.66014.20.20.0.0.0.0.136.1786.9j8.17.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..3.0.0.EdZi4474mYw) might help you.